# Problems with open cart admin panel

Tags: php, opencart

When I open cart admin panel, I get an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function calculate() on a non-object in /home/u371067346/public_html/catalog/controller/module/featured.php on line 38

Code in `featured.php` where error existed:

```
if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product_info['price'], $product_info['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
} else {
    $price = false;
}
```

On my local copy open cart working fine.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're experiencing the error with?

Comment: Please read [What topics can I ask about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)
and [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
And [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: The code provided diesn't help that much. Still, I would check how is `$this->tax` being created

Comment: @Klaod : this issue should come in front-end not in admin

Comment: @zedBlackbeard version 2.0

Comment: @Klaod : is this issue comes in frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because in admin side there is no object created for the tax class (also not necessary), But in the catalog, we need to calculate tax so the object of the `class Tax` created and added to the registry. To know more clearly, have a look at `index.php` file of both catalog and admin folder. You will find `$registry->set('tax', new Tax($registry));` in the `index.php` file of the front-end but not in the `index.php` file of the admin panel.

Comment: and how can i fix this?

Comment: Have a you tried to do like `$this->currency->format($option['price'] + ($this->config->get('config_tax') ? $product['tax'] : 0), $order_info['currency_code'], $order_info['currency_value']);`

Comment: It is not the solution. I mean to say try like this one. Add tax by checking if `config_tax` is enabled. This is just an example and as a reference. Take any idea from it.